# Changing Span Class not working

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have the following code in a webpage and for some reason unbeknown to me it is not working, I have 2 methods to try to change the spans class attribute but it is not working, can someone please point be towards where I have gone wrong? :)

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ChangeClass()
    {
        alert("Clicked!");
        document.getElementById("Search").className = "non-activeTab";
        alert("Changed class!");
        //does not work
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("Search").addEventListener('click' , ChangeClass );
        var elm = document.getElementById("Search").className;
        alert("LOADED PAGE " + elm);
        //this works
    }
    function someFunction(abc,elm) {
        alert(abc + "/" + elm);
        //does not work
    }
</script>

<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
    <div class="tabOutline" id="outline" >
        <span class="activeTab" id="Search" onclick="someFunction('two',this.className)">
            Search
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this not about programming???? If you vote to close and vote down the proper thing to do it to comment why.

Comment: Help yourself by starting to use jQuery.

Comment: fyi, `language="javascript"` is obsolete and not necessary, and @thew: while jquery is nice something that simply does not necessarily need jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but not in the way you might expect. It seems `onclick` executes first, which means it shows you the `className` **before** the change. It does actually change, but you don't see it before you click again.

This is a good example of why it is a bad idea to use both an eventlistener and the `onclick` attribute in the same context. The order of execution is not clear.

To achieve the same in less code you can simply do:

```
<span class="active" onclick="this.className='inactive'">...</span>
```

or:

```
<script>
  onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.target.className = 'inactive';
    });
  };
</script>
<span id="search" class="active">...</span>
```

You can easily test this kind of thing using CSS:

```
<style>
  .active { color: red; }
  .inactive { color: blue; }
</style>
```